# Curly brace in TikZ with round tip and edgy ends

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

I would like to draw exactly this curly brace in TikZ:
[image]

(round tip, edgy ends which end horizontally)

Do you have any idea how to do this?

I can only draw the "normal" curly brace:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[brace1/.style={decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt},
            decorate}]
        \draw [brace1, line width=0.2mm] (3.15,3.7) -- (5.6,3.7);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I defined a `pic` object that depends on an argument (that modifies the scale) that looks like the curly braces you are looking for, I think.  Now, the argument is there in case you might want to do something else with it; strictly speaking, the same effect can be achieved using `scale={...}` as an optional argument when invoking the pic.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  pics/curlyB/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[rounded corners={#1*4}, line cap=round]
        \draw (-#1, -#1/7) |- (-#1/2, 0) -| (0, #1/7);
        \draw (0, #1/7) |- (#1/2, 0) -| (#1, -#1/7);
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) pic[] {curlyB=1};
  \path (0, -1) pic[thick] {curlyB=2};
  \path (0, -2) pic[orange, thick] {curlyB=2.5};
  \path (3, -1) pic[blue, thick, rotate=40] {curlyB=2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```